# Angular-Material: display a tooltip on a form label

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to display a tooltip on a label. Unfortunately this does not work. Is there a simple solution ?

```html
  <mat-form-field >
    <mat-label matTooltip="Please enter your E-Mail Address">
      E-Mail <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
    </mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Enter your email"
      [formControl]="email"
     >
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

See this [Stack-Blitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpnqm5-kac1b4?file=app/form-field-error-example.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the `mat-icon` after your `input` element, as suggested in the Angular Material documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants). It also does look a bit nicer I think, when the icon is right aligned.

```html
<mat-form-field >
  <mat-label>E-Mail</mat-label>
  <input matInput
         placeholder="Enter your email"
         [formControl]="email">
  <mat-icon matSuffix 
            matTooltip="Please enter your E-Mail Address">
    help_outline
  </mat-icon>
  <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I made a Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpnqm5-wzfwze?file=app%2Fform-field-error-example.html).

Answer (score 10):

I use CSS to do this with following code :

```
.mat-form-field-label mat-label {
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```